# Equation number with aligned environment: can I force number placing with long equations?

Tags: numbering, vertical-alignment

These is my (dummy) MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

My aligned equation:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}[b]
    &xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \\
    &xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \\
    &xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}[b]
    &xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\
    &xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \\
    &xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, in the second equation the "equation number" is shifted on a line below because the first line of the equation is too long (but it does not give an overfull).

My question is: can I get an equation number placement, like that one in the first equation, keeping the aligned environment? The solution should be local and must consider that I can have several aligned environment with `center` (standard) or `top` (`[t]`) alignment.

I know I can obtain the same layout with:

```
\begin{align}
    &xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \notag \\
    &xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \notag \\
    &xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{align}
```

[image]

but I'm wondering if there is a quicker way to get it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for some reason, this doesn't seem to work with `aligned` (i'll look into it), but
it *is* possible to reposition the tag if `split` is used:

[image: output of example code]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    &xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\
    &xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \\
    &xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  \end{split}
\raisetag{1\baselineskip}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

the `\raisetag` command is documented in the `amsmath` users guide in section 3.8
on page 8.

Comment: I found that it works when I have `align` combined with `aligned` so the problem should be the `equation` environment. However, this solved my problem. Thank you.